# How Spivak defines $f^*\colon \mathcal{J}^k(W)\to \mathcal {J}^k(V)$

Tags: tensors

Spivak says the following: say we have $f\colon V\to W$, a linear transformation, then we can define $f^*\colon \mathcal{J}^k(W)\to \mathcal {J}^k(V)$ by 
$$f^* T(v_1,\dots,v_k)=T(f(v_1),\dots,f(v_k)),$$
where $T\in\mathcal J^k(W)$ and $v_i\in V$. Here $\mathcal J^k(V)$ is the set of all $k$-tensors on $V$. To me it seems like we have $f^*\colon \mathcal J^k(V)\to\mathcal J^k(W)$, instead of the other way around. Is this a typo of the book?

I can't imagine that $v_i\in V$, while $T\in \mathcal J^k(W)$. Shouldn't $T$ only accept vectors from $W$?

Comment: What exactly is a "$k$-tensor" according to Spivak?

Comment: A function $T\colon V^k\to R$ where $V$ is a vector space, and $T$ is multilinear.

Comment: In that case, then $f^*$ is operating in the right direction. I'd write ${\cal J}^k(V)$ as ${V^*}^{\otimes k}$.

Comment: Oh I think I see it. I was confused by their notation $T(v_1,\dots,v_k)$, as if $T$ is accepting vectors from $V$, while acually, I should think of it as $f^*(T)(v_1,\dots,v_k)$.